# Snowflake Oauth Integration Settings - Changing Endpoint Variables

Tags: oauth, tableau-api, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a need to alter the end-point variables in my Snowflake Oauth Integration I setup for Tableau. The integration was setup using this guide: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/oauth-partner.html#step-1-configuring-an-oauth-integration. The two parameters I need to alter are:

- OAUTH_AUTHORIZATION_ENDPOINT
- OAUTH_TOKEN_ENDPOINT

I need to change the endpoint from "https://account_name.snowflake..." to "https://account-name.snowflake..."

I have tried to do this by:

alter security integration tableau_server set OAUTH_AUTHORIZATION_ENDPOINT = 'https://account-name.snowflakecomputing.com/oauth/authorize';

I get this error: SQL compilation error: invalid property 'OAUTH_AUTHORIZATION_ENDPOINT' for 'INTEGRATION - OAUTH - TABLEAU_SERVER'

I am using the accountadmin role and I can change other parameters, just not these two.

I'm trying to make this change to resolve a SSL certificate error. Apparently domain names that have an underscore "_" do not follow SSL protocol any longer. Replacing the underscore with a dash works to resolve the issue but I need to make this change in my integration settings for SSO to work. Any help on how to get this done is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not an expert in this area, but those 2 parameters are not configurable parameters of your security integration object in Snowflake.  Per the documentation:

> For convenience, Snowflake defines the endpoints when a client is
> registered.

This means they are generated when you create the security integration object using these directions:

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/oauth-custom.html#step-1-create-an-oauth-integration

My interpretation here is that if you wish to modify those, you'd need to create a new security integration (or drop and replace the existing one).

Comment: Thanks Mike! You are correct, these two parameters cannot be modified. Snowflake support confirmed this for me today. I'll need to work with Snowflake to make the modifications I'm looking for. Not able to upvote your answer yet, my account is too new!